# nemo_action not functional, script works though

Tags: linux, synchronization, cloud, linux-mint

On Linux Mint, I'm trying to add to the right-click context menu when selecting a file, by using .nemo_action files. I'm able to add the context menu item, but nothing happens when I execute it.

Here's the nemo_action:

```
[Nemo Action]
Active=true
Exec=python "$HOME/.odrive-agent/bin/odrive.py" sync "%F"
Selection=any
Extension=any;
```

When I use terminal to perform:

```
python "$HOME/.odrive-agent/bin/odrive.py" sync /home/user/file.jpg
```

... it works exactly as it should.

When I right-click and click the context menu, it doesn't work the same way. I tried:

```
Exec=gedit %F
```

... and that opens the file in gedit. But it doesn't work when invoking the other command. I've tried every combination of double quotes, single quotes, no quotes, %f, %F, %N, and %U.